# Is there an add-on that will export entry content as flat file on submit?

Tags: entry, .html

We are looking to convert an EE site to a static site, but leaving two sections of the site in ExpressionEngine. For these two sections, we want to use EE control panel to publish content, but it would be great if on submission of the new entry, the content could also be exported as a flat file (preferably with markdown). Has anyone ever come across such an add-on that will allow for this?

Comment: Are you using MarkDown as your format on text field(s) in the CP already? What field types do you need to export - just textareas?

Comment: No, not currently using MarkDown as format on text fields. We need to export title, content, author, date, etc (text fields and text areas).

Comment: And you want to trigger this action from within the CP, correct?

Comment: That is correct. When a new entry is submitted (or a current entry is edited and submitted), the content of the entry is exported as a MarkDown, HTML, or XML file (preferably MarkDown).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe there's an add-on that does that but you could write a simple extension to do this using the "[entry_submission_absolute_end](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/cp/content_publish/index.html#entry-submission-absolute-end)" hook or a similar [hook](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/cp/content_publish/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used it yet, but this looks like exactly what you need: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/vl-file-generator

Comment: Hmmm, on second thought it looks like that generates a file per-channel rather than per-entry. Maybe could be easily modified to do what you need, though.